# WinEdt LaTeXify macro install fails to install toolbar buttons

Tags: macros, winedt

I just installed the LaTeXify Macro in WinEdt 10.1 20160526 build on 2 computers. First up Win 8.1 box - everything okay! Second up Win 7 box not so much. The main menu TeX -> PDFLaTeXify, Biber, etc. are all there and work fine.

What I would like to see are these compile options in the main toolbar compile button/dropdown menu and Biber visible next to the BibTeX - B button. In a similar situation, the JabRef macro installs a JabRef menu item under the Accessories menu but no button.

How do I get the buttons in the toolbar that should be available, like the Win 8.1 box?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the installation of the add-ons "LaTeXify" and "JabRef" have been successful, then WinEdt toolbar must contain the items related to these packages.

The only reason I see for not having them visible is that you are not using the default toolbar in WinEdt. You must have chosen one of the alternative toolbars available in Options -> Toolbar menu.

In fact, all the add-ons available at winedt.org only modify WinEdt default toolbar, but not the alternative ones.

If you still want to use your alternative toolbar and have the buttons you've mentioned, follow this procedure.

1. Show the "Options Interface" (Options -> Options Interface)

   [image]

   and double-click the "Toolbar" item (`Toolbar.ini` gets opened)
2. In this file you should be able to locate a few lines containing `%%INCLUDE` (they should start at line 122 on your version)

   [image]

   As you can see, only one of these lines is not commented. Double-click upon the word `%%INCLUDE` in the non-commented line (a file with your alternative toolbar gets opened).
3. In this file, locate the lines

   ```
     BUTTON="PDFTeXify"
       NAME="TeX Compile"
       TYPE=8
       MENU="PDFTeXify"
       MENU="PDFLaTeX"
       MENU="PDFTeX"
       MENU="-"
       MENU="TeXify"
       MENU="LaTeX"
       MENU="TeX"
       MENU="AMSTeX"
       MENU="-"
       MENU="ConTeXt"
       MENU="-"
       MENU="LuaLaTeX"
       MENU="LuaTeX"
       MENU="-"
       MENU="XeLaTeX"
       MENU="XeTeX"
     BUTTON="|"
     BUTTON="BibTeX"
     BUTTON="Make_Index"
   ```

   and replace them with

   ```
     BUTTON="PDFLaTeXify"
       NAME="TeX Compile"
       TYPE=8
       MENU="PDFLaTeXify"
       MENU="PDFTeXify"
       MENU="PDFLaTeX"
       MENU="PDFTeX"
       MENU="-"
       MENU="LaTeXify"
       MENU="TeXify"
       MENU="LaTeX"
       MENU="TeX"
       MENU="AMSTeX"
       MENU="-"
       MENU="ConTeXt"
       MENU="-"
       MENU="LuaLaTeXify"
       MENU="LuaTeXify"
       MENU="LuaLaTeX"
       MENU="LuaTeX"
       MENU="-"
       MENU="XeLaTeXify"
       MENU="XeTeXify"
       MENU="XeLaTeX"
       MENU="XeTeX"
       MENU="-"
       MENU="LaTeXify2PDF"
       MENU="TeXify2PDF"
     BUTTON="|"
     BUTTON="Biber"
     BUTTON="BibTeX"
     BUTTON="Make_Index"
     BUTTON="|"
     BUTTON="JabRef"
   ```
4. Now save the file and then run the command Options -> Maintenance -> Rebuild All.

That's all. Now your alternative toolbar contains the wanted items:

[image]

Comment: Works like a charm. Makes life and WinEdt so much easier. Best regards.